# Unable to Write a forecast/list into a Data frame using a Loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, time-series

I am trying to add forecast generated into a new data frame within a for loop so that the first set of time series, which goes into the Holt-Winters function and the forecast for that is generated (the column **mean**) and stored in a dataset and then the next column is added as time series and the same happens till the end.

The error that I am coming across is: `` Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = NULL) :  new columns would leave holes after existing columns ``

Can someone help me with the issue and let me know how to resolve this issue and get the output based on my expectation?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(tidymodels)
library(forecast)
library(prophet)
library(readxl)
library(writexl)
library(tibble)

pd <- readxl::read_excel("C:/X/X/X/Dummy.xlsx")
colnames(pd)[1]="ds"

colnames(pd)
pd1 <- pd %>% select(`X1`,`X2`,`X3`)
    
for(i in 1:ncol(pd1))
{
  Y1 <- ts(data = pd1[,i],
           frequency = 12,
           start = c(2019,1),
           end = c(2022,8))
  print(Y1)
  
  Model_Y1 = HoltWinters(x=Y1,
                         seasonal = 'additive')
  
  Predictions_Y1= forecast(Model_Y1,
                               h=6)
  
  Output_Y1[,i] = Predictions_Y1$Mean
}
```

The Input dataset **pd** which I am working with is:

```
structure(list(ds = c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", 
"2019-04-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-07-01", "2019-08-01", 
"2019-09-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", 
"2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", 
"2020-07-01", "2020-08-01", "2020-09-01", "2020-10-01", "2020-11-01", 
"2020-12-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-04-01", 
"2021-05-01", "2021-06-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-08-01", "2021-09-01", 
"2021-10-01", "2021-11-01", "2021-12-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", 
"2022-03-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-06-01", "2022-07-01", 
"2022-08-01"), X1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 
85, 72, 111, 96, 50, 95, 48, 87, 75, 249, 173, 74, 86, 127, 209, 
92, 137, 49, 84, 75, 73, 376, 196, 91, 107, 124, 177, 244, 275, 
100, 176), X2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 29, 243, 
281, 262, 283, 0, 264, 104, 289, 41, 76), X3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 157, 171, 377, 409, 375, 314, 253, 322, 
130, 472, 115, 179)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -44L))
```

Answer (score 1):

The data frame `Predictions_Y1` must be defined before the for loop, otherwise it can not be found.

However, you just want to apply the function `HoltWinters` to every column of `pd1` and store the results in a new data frame. This can be best archived using `lapply`, e.g. to get the predictions in a new combined table:

```
pd1 |>
  lapply(function(col) {
  Y1 <- ts(
    data = col,
    frequency = 12,
    start = c(2019, 1),
    end = c(2022, 8)
  )
  
  HoltWinters(
    x = Y1,
    seasonal = "additive"
  )$fitted
}) |>
  enframe() |>
  unnest(value)
# A tibble: 96 × 2
#   name  value[,"xhat"] [,"level"] [,"trend"] [,"season"]
#   <chr> <ts>           <ts>       <ts>       <ts>       
# 1 X1    -35.74199      -11.253788 7.407634   -31.895833 
# 2 X1     52.61996        3.066494 7.407634    42.145833 
# 3 X1     46.89648       15.968013 7.407634    23.520833 
# 4 X1     90.81340       27.634934 7.407634    55.770833 
# 5 X1     73.14607       38.467606 7.407634    27.270833 
# 6 X1     20.84797       49.752840 7.407634   -36.312500
```

Comment: Hi @danlooo , This one did not work, can you kindly show me how to define the data frame Predictions_Y1, will Predictions_Y1=data.frame() work ? and write the result from Holt-Winters into the column, by result, I mean the Mean of the forecast generated into Predictions_Y1.